# How can I connect RFID with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, rfid

I have installed hyperterminal for my RFID. When I scan the RFID, the tag is shown on the hyperterminal. I want to create a program using VB.NET that will function like the hyperterminal. When I scan the RFID, data will show and eventually, saving it on the database for further use. Any codes sir? Thanks.

Comment: What port is the RFID reader connected to in Hyper Terminal?

Comment: @EugenRieck. COM15 sir. It functions well sir. Do you want me to post the port settings?

Comment: Try communicating directly with the [serial port](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/37361-serial-port-communication-in-vbnet/) using the given tutorial, looks good on first sight.

Answer (score 2):

Use a serial-to-keyboard utility (such as http://www.brothersoft.com/redirect-serial-port-rs232-to-keyboard-61149.html or http://www.fileguru.com/apps/serial_port_to_keyboard) and use a simple textbox.

This way you get the bonus, that you can type the code, if the Reader can't read it (defective tag)

Comment: I have tried this sir. Yes it functions like the hyperterminal sir. But I need the code sir. Because I will be pasting the code to my program. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: Okay okay. I get it sir. Do you have any code for converting the tag into a simple letter format?